# using an accordion for each record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm passing a list of files along with their directories to my Razor view. I have successfully managed to list them all to facilitate downloading however I have now been asked to organise them in an accordion style.

I am trying to use JqueryUi's accordion however it is proving difficult to implement it whilst using a for each to populate the links.

this is what I have thus far:

```
@foreach (var fullPath in Model)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);

    var parent = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(fullPath);
    string parentString = parent.ToString();

    var downloadPath = @Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath) + "\\" + @fileName;
    string yearOne = Server.MapPath("~/Pdfs/YearOne");
    string yearTwo = Server.MapPath("~/Pdfs/YearTwo");


    <div id="accordion">
        @*<h3>Year One</h3>*@
        @if (parentString == yearOne)
        {
            <div>
                <p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink(fileName, "Download", new { path = downloadPath }) </li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
        }

        @*<h3>Year Two</h3>*@
        @if (parentString == yearTwo)
        {
            <div>
                <p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink(fileName, "Download", new { path = downloadPath }) </li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

What's happening is, its placing the first record in the appropriate accordion section, then the rest are just listed below. Can anyone suggest how I might achieve this requirement within a for each?

Comment: The div elements have the same id "accordion", using class instead of id would make a correct selector.

Comment: Good point, however I will then have multiple accordion's, so I imagine they will not work as one.

Comment: I've changed this and it just puts every link in its own accordion that does nothing because there's only one line per.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of finding which path is for year one and which is for year two could be moved into the controller. The corresponding model could be:

```
public class AccordionModel
{
    public List<string> YearOne { get; set; }
    public List<string> YearTwo { get; set; }
}
```

The view could be changed to:

```
@model AccordionModel

@functions {
    string GetFileName(string path)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
        return fileName;
    }

    string GetDownloadPath(string path)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

        var parent = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(path);
        string parentString = parent.ToString();

        var downloadPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(path) + "\\" + fileName;
        return downloadPath;
    }
}

<div id="accordion">
    @*<h3>Year One</h3>*@
        <div>
            <p>
                <ul>
                    @foreach(var path in Model.YearOne)
                    {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink(GetFileName(path), "Download", new { path = GetDownloadPath(path) }) </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </p>
        </div>

    @*<h3>Year Two</h3>*@
        <div>
            <p>
                <ul>
                    @foreach(var path in Model.YearTwo)
                    {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink(GetFileName(path), "Download", new { path = GetDownloadPath(path) }) </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I happened to do this before you answered, but this is indeed the correct approach, thanks.